# Windows Phone 8 app wakup on bluetooth connection?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible in a Windows Phone 8 app that isn't active to detect Bluetooth connections and react to them?

I want to build a app the does some stuff as soon a the phone connects to the Bluetooth device. I.e. get in range of the device.

I'm realizing that this might be more than one question.

a. is it possible to detect bluetooth connection when the app isn't active.
b. is it possible to "popup" the app if it detects a connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All connections of any kind are suspended when the application is in background mode. Your application cannot really respond to any events at all.

Unfortunately, this is the limitation of the sandboxed app model which lives in isolation from the operating system. When in background, it is suspended and no sensors nor connections live.