# Get a notification when any of the windows phone contacts is added or updated

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my Windows phone app, I store all the contacts in a separate list rather than fetching using Contacts.SearchAsync method whenever I need details about a particular contact.

Now I need to get a notification whenever the user updates, adds or deletes any of the contacts, so that I can keep keep my list updated. How would I do this in Windows phone?

Comment: Do I correctly undarstand? : 1. First time you launch App you make a copy of contacts. 2. You close the App (it doesn't run in background) 3. User adds a contact and you want your list updated?

Comment: Everything correct except the 2nd statement. I don't close the app, it just runs in the background.

Comment: Something like ContentObserver (in android) and QContactManager::contactsAdded event (in blackberry)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can add such an event in WP - I doubt it, if I'm wrong please correct me.
One solution which you may try is to add a background agent which will periodically chcek for changes. But it seems to be a walk around the problem.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx 

I will also recall what @Toni Petrina ansered to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834107/windows-phone-8-app-wakup-on-bluetooth-connection):
"All connections of any kind are suspended when the application is in background mode. Your application cannot really respond to any events at all.

Unfortunately, this is the limitation of the sandboxed app model which lives in isolation from the operating system. When in background, it is suspended and no sensors nor connections live."
So when you leave your App it can't get notification from operating system. Some job can be done only by backgroud agents described at link above.
Maybe upcoming WP 8.1 will change something in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: There is no such notification or event available, you should just check the current list of contacts for changes whenever your app starts.